# Restore Mysql database in Windows Azure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

I'm running a wordpress blog on Windows Azure Website (free).

I've tried to create another blog and use other database. As I'm using a free mode, it denied me to create a new database, so I chose to use the same.

It didn't work and I decided to delete this second site. But now, I can't access my first site.
The error message is : "Error establishing a database connection".

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I contacted ClearDB, because they are responsable for MySQL databases running in Azure, and they restored my DB.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can't restore a deleted MySQL database. Especially in **preview** feature.